# Overlapping regex matches with replace method

Tags: javascript, regex, overlapping-matches

**Regex newbie here!** Lets say i have two arrays of text and I am searching through a text which says.

`let text = This is a cool story.`
I am looking for these phrases in the text.

```
ArrBlue = ["cool story"] 
ArrGreen = ["This is a cool"]
```

And i want to highlight words in the array with the corresponding color. So all the words in ArrBlue will result in text that is blue and ArrGreen in green. I created two new RegExp like so..

```
let regexBlue = new RegExp(arrBlue.join('|'), "ig)  
let regexGreen = new RegExp(arrGreen.join('|'), "ig)
```

and then i use these new variables to then replace text like so attaching a span tag to the beginning and end of the matched expression.

```
let newText = text.replace(regexBlue, "<span class='blue'>$&</span>")    
.replace(regexGreen, "<span class='green'>$&</span>")
```

The issue that i am having is I want my html to look like so..

```
<span class="blue">This is a<span class="green" cool story </span> </span>
```

But in actuality what im getting is

```
This is a <span class="green">cool story</span>
```

Heres my quick snippet to better understand my situation.

```js
let greenListArray = ["cool story"];
let blueListArray = ['This is a cool'];

$("#myform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#results').html('');
   let text = $('textarea#textEntered').val();
   highlightText(text); 
});

function highlightText(text){

let regexGreen = new RegExp(greenListArray.join('[,!?.]?|'), "ig");
let regexBlue = new RegExp(blueListArray.join('[,!?.]?|') + "ig");

let newText = text.replace(regexGreen, "<span class='green'>$&</span>")
.replace(regexBlue, "<span class='blue'>$&</span>");

$('#results').html(newText);
}
```

```css
.blue{
  background-color: red;
  font: red;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}


.greyHighlight:hover{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form id="myform">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea name='textEntered' id='textEntered' />This is a cool story.</textarea>
        <button type='submit' class="bttn">Enter</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
   
    <div class="results-container"> <span class="results-title">Highlighted Text:</span> <div id="results"> </div> <br> </div>


<div class="wantedResults">
Results I wish to have <br>
<span class="blue">This is a</span><span class="green">cool story</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like its working fine already !

Comment: No if you hit enter on the form, what's underneath the "Highlighted Text" is the actual result which is not the same as what i have below. The text underneath "Results I wish to have" is hard coded.

Comment: Yeah. But I checked by giving `Hello cool story` and got the result and saw the HTML structure to be as expected.

Comment: But that wasn't the issue I was trying to solve.  The issue is when there is an overlap of a word in both the arrays only the top one gets replaced with a span tag instead of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for basic implementation. Overlapping more than 2 times will not work properly. And also need to handle white spaces.

```js
var arr = [
  {str:"cool story",
   color: "green"},
   {str:"This is a cool",
   color: "blue"},
   {str:"two best friends",
   color: "red"},
   {str:"about two best",
   color: "yellow"},
];

$("#myform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#results').html('');
   let text = $('textarea#textEntered').val();
   highlightText(text); 
});

function highlightText(text)
{
    for(var index=0;index<arr.length;index++)
    {
        var matches=text.match(arr[index].str.split(" ").join("\\s*(<.*>)*\\s*"));
        if(matches)
        {
            for(var i=1;i<matches.length;i++)
            {
                if(!matches[i]) continue;
                if(matches[i].indexOf("/")==-1)
                {
                    text = text.replace(matches[0],matches[0].replace(matches[i],"")+matches[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                
                    text = text.replace(matches[0],matches[i]+matches[0].replace(matches[i],""));
                }
            }
        }
        text = text.replace(arr[index].str, "<span class='"+arr[index].color+"'>$&</span>");
    }
    $('#results').append($(text))
}
```

```css
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.grey{
  background-color: grey;
}

.greyHighlight:hover{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form id="myform">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea name='textEntered' id='textEntered'>This is a cool story about two best friends.</textarea>
        <button type='submit' class="bttn">Enter</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
   
    <div class="results-container"> <span class="results-title">Highlighted Text:</span> <div id="results"> </div> <br> </div>


<div class="wantedResults">
Results I wish to have <br>
<span class="blue">This is a</span><span class="green">cool story</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This definitely solved my issue! But i was curious if you knew how to solve the issue of if i have repeating phrases lets say "cool story cool story" multiple times it will only highlight the first iteration of when it is seen in the text and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may accomplish what you are wanting. It isn't ideal though, as it won't work if there are multiple layers of `<span>` or `</span>` but it does produce the correct result in your example. Hopefully this will help in some way :)

```js
let greenListArray = ["cool story"];
let blueListArray = ['This is a cool'];

$("#myform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#results').html('');
   let text = $('textarea#textEntered').val();
   highlightText(text); 
});

function highlightText(text){

    // this replaces all spaces with regex that will allow the capturing of html tags '<>'
    // note that I am only doing this for the first element in the array, this would need to loop over the elements if so desired...
    greenListArray[0] = greenListArray[0].replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '( |<.*>| <.*>|<.*> )');
    blueListArray[0] = blueListArray[0].replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '( |<.*>| <.*>|<.*> )');
    
    let regexGreen = new RegExp(greenListArray.join('[,!?.]?|'), "ig");
    let regexBlue = new RegExp(blueListArray.join('[,!?.]?|'), "ig");
    
    
    text = replaceStuffs(text, regexGreen, 'green');
    text = replaceStuffs(text, regexBlue, 'blue');
    $('#results').html(text);
}

function replaceStuffs(text, regex, classToAdd) {
 let matchRegex = regex.exec(text);
 let needToAppend = true;
 
 matchRegex = matchRegex[0]; // grab the matching string... as it seems to always be the first element in the array returned by .exec...
 
 let replacement = matchRegex;
 
 if (matchRegex.indexOf('<span') !== -1 && matchRegex.indexOf('</span>') !== -1) // there is a beginning and ending span tag... we leave it alone
 {
 }
 else if (matchRegex.indexOf('<span') !== -1 && matchRegex.indexOf('</span>') === -1) // there's a beginning tag. we need to find the ending of that tag, and then append our ending </span>
 {
  let regexTemp = new RegExp('<span.*', "ig"); // lets select as much of this beginning tag as we can, so it'll hopefully be unique.
  let str = regexTemp.exec(matchRegex);
  // debugger; <-- this pauses Chrome's execution of JS. useful for testing...
  str = str[0];
  
  regexTemp = new RegExp(str+'.*</span>', "ig"); // use the string we found, look for the closing </span>
  text = text.replace(regexTemp, '$&</span>'); // we have now put our closing span after the closing </span> that we found.
  needToAppend = false; // set a variable so we don't append the </span> again later...
 }
 else if (matchRegex.indexOf('</span>') !== -1) // closing span, no beginning tag... we need to move it...
 {
  replacement = matchRegex.replace('</span>','');
  replacement += '</span>';
 }
 
 replacement = '<span class="'+classToAdd+'">'+replacement+(needToAppend ? '</span>' : '');
 
 text = text.replace(matchRegex, replacement);
 return text;
}
```

```css
.blue{
  background-color: red;
  font: red;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}


.greyHighlight:hover{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form id="myform">
      <fieldset>
        <textarea name='textEntered' id='textEntered' />This is a cool story.</textarea>
        <button type='submit' class="bttn">Enter</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
   
    <div class="results-container"> <span class="results-title">Highlighted Text:</span> <div id="results"> </div> <br> </div>


<div class="wantedResults">
Results I wish to have <br>
<span class="blue">This is a</span><span class="green">cool story</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it could have something to do with "this is a cool" and "cool story" overlapping?
you might be over writing one search with another, especially since you do the latter...
maybe include `</span>` as part of your search, as in

`this is a cool(</span>)?`
or
`cool(</span>)? story`